# how to use class controller functions in command class of symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface, symfony-2.6

I am building a batch file using symfony 2 command class. I have a function which deals with DB from a controller inside a bundle

`class SubmitDisclosureController extends FOSRestController  implements MEAuthController
{
...
    public function discDetails($discId) {

        $emr = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();`

I am calling this from a command `src/AppBundle/Command/BatchJobCommand.php`
 which is as below

```
class BatchJobCommand extends Command
{
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln([
            'User Creator',
            '============',
            '',
        ]);

    // retrieve the argument value using getArgument()
    $output->writeln('First batch job')

    $disc = new SubmitDisclosureController();
    $disc->discDetails('42094');
`
```

If I try to execute it, it gives `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function has() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\GR\
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.
php on line 288`

is it not possible to re-use the code by calling the functions of a controller from a command class?

Comment: Actually what you need is in fact a Service which can be used by both the controller and the command

Comment: @MateiMihai yes, you are right. But this change will affect existing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's saying Matei is exactly what you need : create a Service and use it on each class :

```
class DisclosureService { ...  public function discDetails($discId) {...}  }
```

In your services.yml configuration file, you have to add it.

```
 disclosure:
    class:  Your\Namespace\DisclosureService 
    arguments: ["@doctrine", ...]
```

In your command & controller, you can call the service with :

```
$this->get('disclosure')->discDetails('')
```

Details can be found on the official doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: Note: If you want to use defined services in a command make sure to extend ContainerAwareCommand. Also you need a different code to access the service in the command `$this->getContainer()->get('disclosure');`. Also see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

Comment: Not to nitpick but one of the slightly annoying things about the ContainerAwareCommand and the base Controller class is that the command class does not have a get function.  So your code will not work as posted. Edit: Looks like @Joe beat me by about three seconds.

Answer (score 3):

```
$disc = new SubmitDisclosureController();
$disc->setContainer($this->getContainer());
$disc->discDetails('42094');
```

Will get you past the error message.  However, as @MateiMihai says, a better design would be to move the disc functionality into it's own service and then share it between your controller, command and testing classes. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
`

Comment: I tried your answer. I am getting a new error. `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS'`. I am able to connect to DB in local and it is working fine. This issue is only when I try on command line. Is there any separate setting for OCI8 to use in CLI?

Comment: Nope.  Should be the exact same connection stuff unless you really fooled around with the config files.  But you accepted the other answer so I guess all is well.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it worked for my original post. Now the issue is with system config I guess `Notice: Use of undefined constant OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS - assumed 'OCI_COMM
IT_ON_SUCCESS'`